# Lerna publish fails "No matching version found" when used in another workspace

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

I have a project with two workspaces `/packages/core` and `/packages/client` and client has core added as a dependency:

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.9",
  "dependencies": {},
}

{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.9",
  "dependencies": {
    "core": "^1.0.0-alpha.9",
  },
}
```

If I make a change to both packages, and then try to lerna publish I get an npm error saying the package doesnt exist:

```
npx lerna publish --no-private

lerna ERR! npm ERR! code ETARGET
lerna ERR! npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for core@^1.0.0-alpha.10.
lerna ERR! npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
lerna ERR! npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
lerna ERR!
```

Since lerna doesn't clean up on a failed publish, inspecting the package.json's all the files are properly updated to the new version:

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.10",
  "dependencies": {},
}

{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.10",
  "dependencies": {
    "core": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
  },
}
```

How do I properly use a workspace in another workspace without lerna failing to publish?

I realize this is more of an issue with npm than lerna. If I do `npm i core -w client` after changing the core version manually, it installs fine. Its only when the version is changed and `npm i` is called that npm cannot seem to figure out that it should still be linking to the local version and not going to the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched over to yarn and it works fine.